# Convolution of image by Gaussian Coefficient on Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, smoothing

```
clc;
clear all;
clc;

img = imread ('a.jpg');

img = rgb2gray(img);
figure, imshow(img);

img = double (img);

sigma= 2;
G= zeros(5,5);
for i=1:5
    for j=1:5
        x=[-2,1,0,-1,2];
        y=[-2,1,0,-1,2];
        G(i,j)= exp(-(x(i)^2+y(j)^2)/(2*(sigma^2)));
    end
end

G_=G/sum(sum(G,1),2);

A= conv2(img,G);

figure, imshow(A);
```

This is my code for image smoothing.
I first calculated Gaussian Filter Coefficient Coefficient that is normalized.

For the last line, I tried to do convolution of image by the Gaussian Filter Coefficient, then show the image.
However, it only shows a white empty image.
I think the value for Gaussian Filter Coefficient is correct, so I think the problem is on convolution.

Isn't convolution done by conv2(u,v) on matlab? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there are two small issues:

- `img = double(img)` converts the image type from `uint8` to `double`.
  In MATLAB, image of type `double` applies pixels range [0, 1].
  All pixels above 1 are white, so the displayed image is white.
- The kernel you are using with `conv2` is not normalized.
  You are using `A = conv2(img, G)` when you want to use: `A = conv2(img, G_)`.

---

For the first issue there are two options:

1. Instead of `img = double(img)`, you may use:
   `img = im2double(img)` (gives the same result as `img = double(img)/255`).
2. Keep `img = double(img)`, but convert to `uint8` before `imshow(A)`:
   `imshow(uint8(A))`.

---

Here is (one of the options) for corrected code:

```
clc
clear all

img = imread('a.jpg');

img = rgb2gray(img);
figure, imshow(img);

img = im2double(img); % im2double(img) instead of double(img).

sigma = 2;
G = zeros(5,5);
for i = 1:5
    for j = 1:5
        x = [-2,1,0,-1,2];
        y = [-2,1,0,-1,2];
        G(i,j) = exp(-(x(i)^2+y(j)^2)/(2*(sigma^2)));
    end
end

G_ = G/sum(sum(G,1),2);

A = conv2(img, G_); % G_ instead of G. For better margins: A = conv2(img, G_, 'same');

figure, imshow(A);
```